# @HTML.Partial use generic class for the same property in different classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have in my project several classes that have the same property. Example: PersonID.

This property is linked to Person table, I create a select box with two buttons. Instead of doing this to the views that have PersonID:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersonID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonID)
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("PersonID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListPerson, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="selectItem" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Wanted to use the Partial:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Frame/Person.cshtml", Model)
```

#### Question

How do I in Partial have a model, and use the model of View calling the Partial, which can be of different classes and the same property PersonID, and without having to make more of a Partial with the same HTML, , or not want to use `@model Project.Models.User`, and use a generic.

#### Partial

```
@model Project.Models.User

<div class="col-md-12">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersonID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonID)
  <div class="input-group">
      @Html.DropDownList("PersonID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListPerson, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="selectItem" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span></button>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Derive all relevant models from a base model that only has the `PersonID` property and declare that base model for the partial view.

Comment: Or make the entities implement the same interface.

Comment: would not be ugly interface with one property?

Comment: It's just an option, either way works well. I usually use inheritance on my entities as they usually have an `ID` property as a primary key. Also, an interface with only one property isn't ugly really. I have seen and used interfaces with no properties before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways (there are probably more ways, but these are likely the most common)

---

**Option 1 - Interfaces**

First create an interface class, for example:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

Now for each entity that has a person ID, make it implement that interface:

```
public class SomeEntity : IPerson
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    //snip
}
```

Now a view might look like this:

```
@model YourNamespace.IPerson

The person ID is @Model.PersonID
```

---

**Option 2 - Inheritance**

Your base class:

```
public abstract class PersonBase
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

And the entities inherit from the base like this:

```
public class SomeEntity : PersonBase
{
    //snip
}
```

And your view is almost exactly the same:

```
@model YourNamespace.PersonBase

The person ID is @Model.PersonID
```